# Identification of Sunbirds

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

[image]

**Location**: Asansol-Durgapur region, West Bengal, India

**Question**:

Do they belong to the same species?

**Note**:

- I presume the bird in Pic-1 is a male  Purple-rumped sunbird (*Leptocoma zeylonica*).
- I think the birds in Pictures : 2-5 could be non breeding male Purple sunbird (*Nectarinia asiatica*) because they match very much with the Wikipedia description though the bird in Pic-2 has a short tail.
- Pic-4 and Pic-5 capture the same bird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bird in Picture-1 is  Purple-rumped sunbird (*Leptocoma zeylonica*) according to this decription from wikipedia:

> The males have a dark maroon upperside with a blue-green crown that glistens at some angles, bright green shoulder patch and violet/purple rump patch which is generally hidden under the wings. The underparts are whitish with dark throat, maroon breast band and purple/violet patch in the throat which is visible in some angles.

[image]

The birds in Pictures 2-5 is a single species, non-breeding male of purple sunbird (*Cinnyris asiaticus*) according to this description:

> The male is glossy metallic purplish black on the upper parts with the wings appearing dark brown. The breeding male has the underparts also of the same purplish black, but non-breeding males may show a central streak of black on yellow underparts.

[image]

References:

1. Wikipedia
2. r/whatsthisbird